# Properties of the Fourier transform of a certain function

Tags: analysis, special-functions

In my research I met the Fourier transform of the function $f(x)=(1+x^2)^{-1/2}$. I was not able to find its explicit formula. Is this a function known as a 'special function'? I would like to know if it is nonnegative, summable, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fourier transform is defined by $\;\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi ikx}\,dx\;$ then the answer is $$\sqrt{\frac 2{\pi}}K_0(|t|)$$

as provided by [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FourierTransform%5B1/Sqrt%5B1%2bx%5E2%5D,x,t%5D) or in the [Wolfram functions 'transforms'](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/22/ShowAll.html) of the [modified Bessel $K$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_%3a_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1).

This definition from [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E6) (and all information there !) may be the most appropriate :
$$K_0(x)=\int_0^\infty \cos(x\;\sinh(t))dt=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x\;t)}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt$$
(remembering that $\;\displaystyle\operatorname{argsinh}'(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ $)

Comment: Great, many thanks! It would also be nice to decide if it is summable.

Comment: @deltuva: Well the last integral doesn't converge for $x=0$ since the integrand is equivalent to $\frac 1t$ for $t\gg 1$ ($x>0$ is asked at DLMF) and $\int_0^\infty \frac{|\cos(x\;t)|}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt$ will be divergent too so that the convergence is conditional if this is the question.

Comment: I mean, whether or not $K_0$ (the Fourier transform of my $f$) is summable.

Comment: Apparently, it belongs to all $L^p$ with $p>1$, but it may also belong to $L^1$ due to some interference. I am not sure if this is an easy question, but this is what I really need.

Comment: @deltuva: The asymptotic behavior is $K_n(z)\sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2z}}e^{-z}(1+O(\frac 1z))$ so that you shouldn't have many convergence problems for positive values of $z$ (I would say too : for all $L^p$ with $p>1$).

Comment: Isn't it strange that the function behaves like $|x|^{-1}$ while its Fouries transform decays so fast? (It seems I will need some time to understand the whole thing.)

Comment: @deltuva: In distribution theory when we consider tempered functions we find that a function bounded by $A\,x^p$ has a Fourier transform bounded by $\frac B{x^{p+2}}$ (after verification!) but distribution theory is much more permissive for the functions admitting a Fourier transform.